# iTunes style grid, cant click on squares

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an iTunes style grid. I looks like this:

`http://jsfiddle.net/CM8SX/2/`

```
$(myApp.boxes[0]).click(function(){
        if((myApp.boxes_1).css('margin-top') == '0px'){
            $('.grid').slice(5, 10).transition({marginTop: wys[0]}, 400);
            $('.grid').slice(10, 15).transition({marginTop: '0px'}, 400);
        }else {
            $('.grid').slice(5, 10).transition({marginTop: '0px'}, 400);
        }
    });
    $(myApp.boxes[1]).click(function(){
        if((myApp.boxes_1).css('margin-top') == '0px'){
            $('.grid').slice(5, 10).transition({marginTop: wys[1]}, 400);
            $('.grid').slice(10, 15).transition({marginTop: '0px'}, 400);
        }else {
            $('.grid').slice(5, 10).transition({marginTop: '0px'}, 400);
        }
    });
    $(myApp.boxes[5]).click(function(){
        if((myApp.boxes_2).css('margin-top') == '0px'){
            $('.grid').slice(10, 15).transition({marginTop: wys[2]}, 400);
            $('.grid').slice(5, 10).transition({marginTop: '0px'}, 400);
        }else {
            $('.grid').slice(10, 15).transition({marginTop: '0px'}, 400);
        }
    });
```

**Try to click on 1, 2 and 6 square. The problem is when you click on 1, and then on 2 square, the first square hides before. Only then you can show it.**

Comment: Could you add a line that closes all of the other open boxes before opening the one you've clicked on?

Comment: @kthornbloom Solved. Your answer helped me a lot. I've used removeClass() and toggleClass() functions. Thanks!